# Authenticated WMS not accessible through ArcCatalog?

Tags: geoserver, wms, web-service, arccatalog, authentication

I have a Geoserver WMS which has basic authentication for several layers that have data security restrictions against them.

After putting in the username and password in ArcCatalog's add WMS server facility, I am noticing these layers are not showing (layers that do not have any restrictions against them do show).
Are there any known issues with connecting to authenticated WMS services? Do I need to configure anything?

I am using ArcCatalog 10.2.